# Why does 1 && 2 return 2?

Tags: javascript, console.log

Why does the expression `1 && 2` evaluate as 2?

```js
console.log("1 && 2 = " + (1 && 2));
```

Comment: It's called Boolean shortcut's.  You can do similar things with `||`.  eg.. `0 || 1 || 2" would return 1, where `0 && 1 && 2` would return 0.  This is because in the first example `||` when it hits 1, the OR condition is met, it need not go any further and short circuit the rest.  Where with the AND &&, the first condition make the and impossible so short circuits the 1 & 2..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

&& (and operator) returns the last (right-side) value as long as the chain is "truthy".

if you would try 0 && 2 -> the result would be 0 (which is "falsy")

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

> `expr1 && expr2` returns `expr1` if it can be converted to `false`; otherwise, returns `expr2`. Thus, when used with Boolean values, `&&` returns `true` if both operands are true; otherwise, returns `false`.

Because 1 can be evaluated to `true`, `1 && 2` returns `2`.

Answer (score 0):

According to this page:

[Why 1 && 2 == 2](https://javascript.info/logical-operators)

> AND returns the first falsy value or the last value if none were found.
> OR returns the first truthy one.

For multiple operators in same statement:

> precedence of the AND && operator is higher than OR ||, so it executes before OR.
>
> alert( 5 || 1 && 0 ); // 5

Comment: Explained and gave another link. Please check that

Answer (score 0):

Because its `and`, all the values need to be evaluated only up to the first 0, and the value of the last evaluation is returned, and it's the last one.

Although not directly relevant here, note that there's a difference between `bitwise` and `logical` operators. The former tests bits that are the same and only return those, the latter reduces to only `true` (!=0) or `false` (=0), so contrary to intuition, `bitwise AND` and `AND` are not interchangable unless the values are exactly `0` or `1`.